# AS3 Pause code executing to wait a a timer event

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, sleep

I need in my code to pause code execution in a method (continuing with current frame animation) and continue it after 4 seconds
i don't want to use atimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE , anotherMethod); because i'm already in a method and it will send me in another method, i want it just to pause the execution for 4 seconds... how can I do that?

Comment: you do not stop the execution of code, you simply set a timer/timeout which calls a method when the time has elapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function yourFunction():void {

   //code you are executing before

   setTimeout(function() {
      //code you want to execute in 4 seconds
      }, 4000);
}
```